# Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The configuration for the "user" component must contain a "class" element.'

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

hello I got errors by this following errors when I run a command on composer `Yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations like this`

in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php:204
Stack trace:

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php(260): yii\di\ServiceLocator->set('user', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(172): yii\di\ServiceLocator->setComponents(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(529): yii\base\Component->__set('components', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php(105): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\console\Application), Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(205): yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(89): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\yii(26): yii\console\Application->__construct(Array)
#7 {main}

heres my `config\main.php

'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'modules'    => [
         'admin'     => [
                'class' => 'mdm\admin\Module',
                        ],
                    ],
    'components' => [
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager', // or use 'yii\rbac\PhpManager'
    ],
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'mdm\admin\models\User',
        'loginUrl' => ['admin/user/login'],
    ]
]
];
`
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if the answer is still open, but I ran into the same problem today and got a fix for you:

In your `config/main.php` is the 'user' component defined. This is ok for a Web-Application, but the Console-Application needs a config with a 'class' entry. So add a 'class' information in the configuration array and everything is fine:

```
'user' => [
    'class' => 'mdm\admin\models\User',
    'identityClass' => 'mdm\admin\models\User',
    'loginUrl' => ['admin/user/login'],
]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: If I do like this, it works in the command line, but in the browser, it shows an error Setting unknown property: common\models\Person::identityClass. I am using Person Class, instead of User class.

Comment: Helped me as well. not sure why these tutorial writers don't include this line?